# Does altering or drop-recreating a table in oracle affects the policies defined on it

Tags: oracle, row-level-security

If i have a table and a defined policy on it then do I need to redefine the policy if I drop and recreate the table or alter it, provided that the alteration or the recreation of the table does not alter elements that the function needs to see?

Comment: Yes, I do believe dropping a table breaks all policies bound to it.  However, as far as altering goes, I'm not sure.  Could you be more specific on the policy, table schema and what you would like to change?

Comment: Some collegues of mine altered a view on a table so that a column was defined as to_date(B) instead of B. Now the policy I have on this view does not care about this column. It just says that "if the user is 'USERNAME' then return the predicate: "where user_id = user". So it is unnafected by the alter. So the question is if I must redefine the policy even if I will not change anything in the definition. I also expanded my question so that if a drop-create happens will i have to recreate the policy. I cannot test it now (i am on vacation) and have no access. So I would like to know if they must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "do I need to redefine the policy if I
>   drop and recreate the table"

Yes.  Let's create a policy.

```
SQL> exec dbms_rls.add_policy('APC', 'T23', 'DEPTPOL', 'APC', 'security_policies.get_deptno_predicate')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from user_policies;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> exec security_policies.set_deptno(20)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         6

SQL>
```

so that works.  But if we drop and re-create the table (using a backup I prepared earlier) ...

```
SQL> drop table t23
  2  /

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t23 as select * from t23a
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from t23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        11

SQL> exec security_policies.set_deptno(20)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        11

SQL> SQL> select count(*) from user_policies;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

> "So the question is if I must redefine
>   the policy even if I will not change
>   anything in the definition."

No.  Providing the change doesn't invalidate the generated predicate altering a table doesn't drop the policy:

```
SQL> exec dbms_rls.add_policy('APC', 'T23', 'DEPTPOL', 'APC', 'security_policies.get_deptno_predicate')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter table t23 modify deptno number(3,0)
  2
SQL> desc t23
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(12 CHAR)
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 AGE                                                NUMBER(4)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)

SQL> alter table t23 modify deptno number(3,0)
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> exec security_policies.set_deptno(20)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         6

SQL>
```

Note that the change modified the column which is tested by the predicate and the policy still remains in force.

---

> "does a 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW'
>   statement drops and recreates it or
>   does it alter it?"

Let's try it:

```
SQL> create view v23 as select * from t23;

View created.

SQL> exec dbms_rls.add_policy('APC', 'V23', 'DEPTPOLV', 'APC', 'security_policies.get_deptno_predicate')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec security_policies.set_deptno(10)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from v23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5

SQL> create or replace view v23 as select name, age from t23;

View created.

SQL> select count(*) from v23;
select count(*) from v23
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28113: policy predicate has error


SQL>
```

Okay, so that's an error because the view's new projection doesn't include the column in the predicate.  But it suggests teh ploicy is still in place.  So let's fix that error:

```
SQL> create or replace view v23 as select name, age, deptno from t23;

View created.

SQL> select count(*) from v23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. One last detail: If a view exists , does a 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW' statement drops and recreates it or does it alter it? 
If it is the first then I need to redefine the policy, if it is the second then i guess policy is still there... I am correct? (The policy is defined on a view and it was the view that they changed through the CREATE OR REPLACE stm)

Comment: Thanks. If i could I would upvote you a 1000 times just for the way you answered. BTW how do you do it? I mean how do you find the will to spend time explaining when you could devote that time to discover even more? I find myself very eager to explore and create but never to explain, except from when I explain as a means to refine my knowledge... It is very bad but I find it very difficult to get rid of this habit. It is not from selfishness, it is just that whenever there is nothing new on the table, I cant help but procrastinate...

Comment: Personally, I think that explaining something to someone else is a good way of reinforcing your own learning. Secondly, using a real example (like APC) is a good way to check that your own assumptions are right. And as Tom Kyte continually reminds us, our assumptions about Oracle 9 can be wrong on 10,11,etc - nothing beats checking rather than trusting.